# No puedo usar mis clases Java trabajando con Jasper Report : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft

Estoy trabajando con Jasper Report (librería de Java para generar informes) y lo estoy haciendo mediante el IDE de JasperSoft Studio 6.17 -aparentemente su última versión estable-

Soy capaz de generar informes con distintos orígenes de datos y exportarlos en diferentes formatos. Hasta ahí bien.

El problema viene cuando trato de usar una de mis clases para extender la funcionalidad del informe, e invocar por ejemplo a una función mía de una clase Java (a modo de expression) o usar una clase mía como Scriptlet.

He tratado mil y una formas de importar mi código configurando el classpath y no hay manera. Aparentemente, adjunto imagen, las dependencias del proyecto son correctas, pero es imposible evitar la dichosa excepción ClassNotFoundException cuando trato de referirme a una de mis clase.

Parece que las reconoce (las puedes enlazar desde diversos menús de propiedades), o ponerlas en la plantilla, pero no hay manera de referir mis clases desde el informe sin obtener la excepción. Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, gracias.

pd: estoy generando los informes declarativamente, mediante las plantillas jrxml. No de forma programática.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la clase que no está encontrando? ¿Te fijaste si cuenta con [estas dependencias](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.17.0)?

Comment: @padaleiana Las de mi src, no las encuentra ( por ejemplo, MiScriptelet.java ). Sí, esas dependencias que enlazas están en la biblioteca JasperReport Library, correctamente importada, reconocida y usada en la generación del informe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado. Tras preguntar a la comunidad de Jasper Report en su foro, me han comentado que es un fallo, que se resuelve

1. añadiendo una librería java (jar) extra a la carpeta de instalación `/plugin` de JasperSoft
2. lanzando el IDE con la opción `-clean`.

Aquí los detalles: https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/13616#comment-873711

Me comentan además que en estos días hay una nueva versión en lanzamiento que subsana este error.